# Mystery Bug in Javascript Calculation

Tags: javascript, event-handling, calculation

I've tried posting this twice before but it keeps getting deleted as being too similar to a previous question.  However, that previous issue appears to be about how to prevent a form from being submitted, while my problem is how to prevent a prevention.  (Unless, of course, there is something I don't understand about preventDefault, which could well be.)

I have written a flash app and used javascript to calculate certain fields based on user input. When the user inputs a value, the answer to the calculation flashes in the output area, then disappears and the page seems to automatically refresh (i.e., the input disappears and the page scrolls up to the top).
If I clear the cache and refresh the page a number of times (sometimes just once or twice, sometimes many many times), the page will start to work correctly. But the next time I launch it, the same thing happens. However, the app works when user selects an input value from the pop-up of previously used values.

I get no error messages.  I do not understand what in my code could be causing this to happen. Here is the code for the two calculated fields.  In the first, user inputs a number representing employee turnover rate and calculation returns the difference in expense associated with that turnover rate compared to present turnover rate.  In the second, user inputs an employee id number and calculation returns odds that that employee will leave the company.

```
d3.json('/turnover_cost', function(data) {
    var turnover = (Object.values(data[5]))
    var avg_cost = data[2].avg_cost
    var total_cost = data[3].total_cost
    var total_display_cost = total_cost.toLocaleString('en-US')
    var total_employees = data[0].total_employees

    d3.select("#currentRate").text(`Current Turnover Rate:  ${turnover}%`)
    d3.select("#currentCost").text(`Estimated Cost of Current Turnover:  $${total_display_cost}`)

    input = d3.select("#new_rate")
    input.on("change", runEstimate)


    function runEstimate() {
        var new_rate = (d3.select("#new_rate").node().value / 100)
        var new_cost = (avg_cost * (new_rate * total_employees))
        var difference = (parseInt(total_cost - new_cost))
        var post = difference.toLocaleString('en-US')
        d3.select("#cost_diff").text(`$${post}`)
        d3.select("#new_rate").node().value = "";
        console.log(difference)
    }
})

d3.json('/employee_data', function(data) {
    input = d3.select("#emp_num")
    input.on("change", runPredict)

    function runPredict() {
        inputted_num = d3.select('#emp_num').node().value;
        const found = data.some(el => el.employee_number == inputted_num);
        if (!found) prediction = "Number not found";

        var prediction
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (inputted_num == data[i].employee_number) {
                prediction = (data[i].loss_probability).toFixed(1);
            }
        }
        d3.select("#prediction").text(`${prediction}%`);
        d3.select("#emp_num").node().value = "";
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form id="rate">
                    <input type="float" id="new_rate">&emsp; &emsp; &emsp;
                    <ouput type="integer" id="cost_diff">
                        <br><br>

                </form>

                <form id="predict">
                   <input type="integer" id="emp_num">&emsp; &emsp; &emsp;
                   <ouput type="float" id="prediction">
                            <br><br>
                </form>
```

Comment: *I have written a flash app* !?!?!? it is 2021

Comment: Also, you did not post your HTML, but the problem is likely that you have a `<button>` that is not explicitly `type="button"` so a `<form>` is being submitted and reloading your page.

Comment: @Pointy  I've added my html code.  I don't think the input type is the issue since..  there's no button involved; just a field that gets filled.